# LU Factorization with OpenMPI and send-ahead

Tags: c, mpi, numeric

I am trying to implement the LU factorization of the vandermonde matrix with OpenMPI.
Therefore, the matrix is split onto the processors in a cycle-wise manner, e.g. processor 0 gets rows 0, 3, 6, 9 and so on.
In iteration k, every process needs to use row k. The corresponding processor should send it already at the end of iteration k-1 with a non-blocking broadcast, and any other processor should receive it at the beginning of iteration k.
What I did:
Row 0 is send before iterating over k by Process 0.
At the beginning of iteration k:

```
int source = k%size;
if (source != rank)
{   
     printf("Process %d waits for row %d from process %d\n", rank, k, source);
     MPI_Irecv(bcast_buffer, n, MPI_DOUBLE, source, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
     MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
     printf("Process %d received row %d from process %d and continues\n", rank, k, source);
}
```

And the end of iteration k (l2gl is local to global for row indices)

```
// if current row (i) is row k+1
if((l2gl[i]==k+1) && (l2gl[i]!=n-1))
{   
    // Safe row to broadcast buffer and send it to any other process
    for(tmp=0; tmp<n; tmp++)
    {   
        bcast_buffer[tmp] = A[i][tmp];
    }
    for(int r=0; r<size; r++)
    {
        printf("Process %d sends row %d to process %d\n", rank, k+1, r);
        MPI_Isend(bcast_buffer, n, MPI_DOUBLE, r, k+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    }
}
```

In the output I find the following:

```
Process 3 received row 6 from Process 2 and continues
Process 2 received row 5 from Process 1 and continues
Process 2 sends row 6 to Process 0
Process 2 sends row 6 to Process 1
Process 2 sends row 6 to Process 2
Process 2 sends row 6 to Process 3
```

Does it definitely mean that I have an error in communication or may the prints be in a 'wrong' order due to delays of the print output or whatever?
As the result of the factorization is wrong, there has to be a mistake, either in the communication or the calculation.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: There is no global ordering of the output. Note `MPI_Irecv()` immediately followed by `MPI_Wait()` is logically equivalent to `MPI_Recv()`. The latter should be preferred for both readability and performance. If you really want to perform a non blocking broadcast, then you can use `MPI_Ibcast()`

Comment: I used `MPI_Ibcast()` before, the problem, but it was easier to use `MPI_Isend()` because auf the sending condition. Otherwise, every process has to find out who the sender/source is.
Moreover I wanted to make use of the tag.
I thought I had to use a corresponding `MPI_Irecv()`, that is why I used it with `MPI_Wait()`

Comment: It is perfectly valid to `MPI_Isend()` on one end, and `MPI_Recv()` on the other end.